# import images are default to exclude on dataflow

Tags: magento-1.9, import, dataflow, import-products

I am importing images with dataflow, and all looks fine, however after I import they are all pre-selected as excluded:
[image]
I am uploading a csv file with sku and image and it should have one more column for setting of exclude however I don't know how to do it.

CSV File:
[image]

Comment: show your CSV column.

Comment: @SureshChikani I added

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query to change their status to not-excluded

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value SET disabled = 0
```

This will update all your images (excluded) to non-excluded.